# Pandas: duplicating dataframe entries while column higher or equal to 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe containing clinical readings of hospital patients, for example a similar dataframe could look like this

```
   heartrate  pid  time
0         67  151   0.0
1         75  151   1.2
2         78  151   2.5
3         99  186   0.0
```

In reality there are many more columns, but I will just keep those 3 to make the example more concise.

I would like to "expand" the dataset. In short, I would like to be able to give an argument `n_times_back` and another argument `interval`.

For each iteration, which corresponds to `for i in range (n_times_back + 1)`, we do the following:

- Create a new, unique pid `[OLD ID | i]` (Although as long as the new
  `pid` is unique for each duplicated entry, the exact name isn't
  really important to me so feel free to change this if it makes it
  easier)
- For every patient (pid), remove the rows with `time` column which is
  more than the `final time of that patient - i * interval`. For
  example if `i * interval = 2.0` and the times associated to one `pid`
  are `[0, 0.5, 1.5, 2.8]`, the new times will be `[0, 0.5]`, as `final
  time - 2.0 = 0.8`
- iterate

Since I realize that explaining this textually is a bit messy, here is an example.

With the dataset above, if we let `n_times_back = 1` and `interval=1` then we get

```
   heartrate    pid  time
0         67  15100   0.0
1         75  15100   1.2
2         78  15100   2.5
3         67  15101   0.0
4         75  15101   1.2
5         99  18600   0.0
```

For `n_times_back = 2`, the result would be

```
   heartrate    pid  time
0         67  15100   0.0
1         75  15100   1.2
2         78  15100   2.5
3         67  15101   0.0
4         75  15101   1.2
5         67  15102   0.0
6         99  18600   0.0
```

`n_times_back = 3` and above would lead to the same result as `n_times_back = 2`, as no patient data goes below that point in time

I have written code for this.

```
def expand_df(df, n_times_back, interval):
    for curr_patient in df['pid'].unique():
        patient_data = df[df['pid'] == curr_patient]
        final_time = patient_data['time'].max()
        for i in range(n_times_back + 1):
            new_data = patient_data[patient_data['time'] <= final_time - i * interval]
            new_data['pid'] = patient_data['pid'].astype(str) + str(i).zfill(2)
            new_data['pid'] = new_data['pid'].astype(int)
            #check if there is any time index left, if not don't add useless entry to dataframe
            if(new_data['time'].count()>0):
                df = df.append(new_data)
        df = df[df['pid'] != curr_patient]  # remove original patient data, now duplicate
    df.reset_index(inplace = True, drop = True)
    return df
```

As far as functionality goes, this code works as intended. However, it is very slow. I am working with a dataframe of 30'000 patients and the code has been running for over 2 hours now.

Is there a way to use pandas operations to speed this up? I have looked around but so far I haven't managed to reproduce this functionality with high level pandas functions

Comment: Can you edit your explanation (I would like to...) in a step-wise way? so that it is more understandable.

Comment: I have rewritten the explanation, let me know if it's clearer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ended up using a groupby function and breaking when no more times were available, as well as creating an "index" column that I merge with the "pid" column at the end.

```
def expand_df(group, n_times, interval):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    final_time = group['time'].max()
    for i in range(n_times + 1):
        new_data = group[group['time'] <= final_time - i * interval]
        new_data['iteration'] = str(i).zfill(2)
        #check if there is any time index left, if not don't add useless entry to dataframe
        if(new_data['time'].count()>0):
            df = df.append(new_data)
        else:
            break
    return df

new_df = df.groupby('pid').apply(lambda x : expand_df(x, n_times_back, interval))
new_df = new_df.reset_index(drop=True)
new_df['pid'] = new_df['pid'].map(str) + new_df['iteration']
```